# forbid yarn check version when yarn install

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I run yarn in a offline computer,when I run `yarn add xxx` is very slow,because it read yarn version from yarnpkg.com.how to forbid this.

```
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 1 new dependency.
info Direct dependencies
└─ typescript@3.7.4
info All dependencies
└─ typescript@3.7.4
Done in 4.82s.
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
verbose 23.339149829 Performing "GET" request to "https://yarnpkg.com/latest-version".
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
verbose 46.36636041 Performing "GET" request to "https://yarnpkg.com/latest-version".
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
verbose 69.392200426 Performing "GET" request to "https://yarnpkg.com/latest-version".
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
verbose 92.418733958 Performing "GET" request to "https://yarnpkg.com/latest-version".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. using option `--non-interactive`
2. add option `disable-self-update-check` to yarn config file

Comment: thank you. `yarn  config set disable-self-update-check true`